# IPCam's sd card access by cgi-http method(dlink dcs-942l) on android phone

Tags: android, cgi, android-videoview, http-authentication, ip-camera

I'm going to develop an ipcam `security` app on my android phone, and need to access to SD card of ipcam through HTTP request, to play a saved video, and I have two problem:

- when access with browser to a specific video( I know the specific URL), it ask me login and video start, while in my application I don't know how implement with specific http session, and VideoView doesn't start the video( I suppose that it requires an authentication).

I RESOLVED THE AUTHORIZATION!!!

- I want to create a explorer_path-like to choose what video reproduce with video View.
  I mapped the http/tcp interaction between ip-cam e phone but I don't know how take http message after the response of server that the cam send how html text to build the web pages

  ```
  <formatsdcard>Format SD Card</formatsdcard>
  <description1>Click this icon to automatically format the SD Card and create folder for video.</description1>
  <description2>If the recorded files are stored on the SD Card,click on the recorded folder and choose the recorded file you would like to view.</description2>
  <description3>If video files are stored on the SD Card, click on the video folder and choose the video file you would like to view.</description3>
  <description4>Reloads the file and folder information from the SD Card.</description4>
  <format>Format SD Card - </format>
  <view>View Recorded files -</view>
  <playback>Playback Recorded Video - </playback>
  <refresh>Refresh - </refresh>



  <totalcapacity></totalcapacity>
  <availablespace></availablespace>
  <usedspace>xxxxxx</usedspace>
  <modelUsedSpace>0</modelUsedSpace>
  <folderstring>
  VIDEO1.avi:f:CAMPO1*VIDEO2.avi:f:CAMPO2*...OTHER VIDEO IN THE CURRENT DIRECTORY
  </folderstring>
  <folderpath>PARENT-DIRECTORY/CURRENT-DIRECTORY</folderpath>
  <filesperpage>5</filesperpage>
  <currentpage>1</currentpage>
  <totalpages>1</totalpages>
  </playback>
  </config>
  </root>
  ```

I want to take the information about :

```
    <folderstring>
    VIDEO1.avi:f:CAMPO1*VIDEO2.avi:f:CAMPO2*...OTHER VIDEO IN THE CURRENT DIRECTORY
    </folderstring>
    <folderpath>PARENT-DIRECTORY/CURRENT-DIRECTORY</folderpath>
```

Comment: i resolved the part about authorization by request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString("user:password".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP)); thanks wireshark program i mapped the http traffic and resolved it.

Comment: All resolved month ago.